# C++11 constexpr string implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Is there a way to implement strings to work both at compile time and run time?

AFAIK for a class to be constexpr constructed it needs to have a trivial destructor.  However, this proves difficult when we're dealing with strings.  If the string is NOT constexpr, then it needs to deallocate memory.  However, if it IS constexpr, then it is statically allocated and shouldn't be deleted, thus allowing a trivial destructor.

However, it's not possible to say "Hey, Compiler!  If I'm constexpr, you don't need to destruct me!" Or is it?

It would be something like the following:

```
class string {
private:
    char * str;
public:
    template<std::size_t l>
    constexpr string(const char (&s)[l]) : str(&(s[0])) {}
    string(const char * s) { str = strdup(s); }
    static if (object_is_constexpr) {
        ~string() = default;
    }
    else {
        ~string() { free(str); }
    }
};
```

The closest I've been able to come is having two separate types, string and constexpr_string, a user-defined literal _string returning constexpr_string, and a user-defined implicit conversion from constexpr_string to string.

This isn't very nice though, as `const auto s = "asdf"_string;` works but `const string s = "asdf"_string;` does not.  Additionally, a reference/pointer to a constexpr_string won't convert.  Inheritance either way causes un-intuitive "gotcha"s, and doesn't resolve the first problem.

This seems like it should be possible, as long as the compiler were to TRUST the programmer that the constexpr didn't need to be destructed.

If I have a misconception let me know.

Comment: I think you're looking for `strwrap` from http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/parsing-strings-at-compile-time-part-i/

Comment: String Literals `const char (&Var)[N]` _are_ the `constexpr` string type.

Comment: You've got to love when people start using features like `static if` before they are approved!

Comment: @David: I for one would not approve a feature if people weren't already trying to use it. The technical term for such features is "useless" ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well, there are many rough corners with the proposals and the language, the first of which is how it interacts with two-phase lookup (which is not an issue in D). Then again, there are some proposals accepted that were not being used (consider rvalue-references), but were clearly an improvement. There is a great difference between *having an implementation and use cases* and it being used in SO. Also note, that was no criticism, but praise on the proposal: it is good enough for people to start using it after just hearing the concept!

Answer (score 11):

It's not only a matter of destruction.

A `constexpr` operation should only call other `constexpr` operations and `new`, `malloc` etc... are *not* `constexpr`. Note that this is a statically checked property and does not depend on the runtime argument, so the call to such function must be absent altogether, and not merely hidden in a branch that is (supposedly) not taken.

As such, it will never be possible to get a `constexpr` `string`.

Comment: It can't even be in a non-constexpr constructor?  It seems like it should be possible to have both constexpr and non-constexpr constructors for a given type, just as it is possible to have const and non-const methods.

Comment: You can totally make a `constexpr` string-type, it just won't be able to handle non-constexpr strings.  Just make conversion functions.

Comment: The way I see it, constexpr is a way to blur the line between compile time and run time computation. Primitive types allow this, and it seems like it should be possible to do some things to allow pointers in classes to either point to a literal or dynamically allocated memory. Functional languages have abstracted over the compile time/run time boundary for quite some time now. @Mooing Duck: conversion functions seem to break the abstraction

Comment: @RobertMason: the heap is _highly_ runtime dependant (and stateful) and cannot be executed at compile time.  Period.  The best you can do is just do it at runtime at startup.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I *know* that the heap is runtime dependent.  I implemented a very *bad* one for my toy kernel's runtime.  What I'm saying is that if it's constexpr, then it points to a literal that's defined somewhere in the .data segment.  Since we KNOW it's constexpr at compile time (by definition), we know we don't need to delete it.  If you write the class well, then if you make a run time (non constexpr) object from it, you copy the literal to the heap at run time to take ownership, or set a flag and do a COW.  In the constexpr case, the destruction needed is trivial - it's in .data.

Comment: To clarify- only if it's a non-constexpr string do you actually *need* to do _any_ destruction.  And this is something the compiler already knows - all that is necessary is a way to TELL it that.

Comment: "You can totally make a constexpr string-type, it just won't be able to handle non-constexpr strings. ". That's not true at all. A non-owning runtime string class is totally feasible. Aka' stringref.

Comment: @RobertMason: So you want a string type that keeps it's contents in `.data`? C++ has that built in.  String literals.  And they interact with `std::string` in every useful way.  I don't understand the goal here I guess.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I was looking more towards a string type that allows transformations on it to be done at compile time or at run time.  If it's a literal, it does the computation at compile time, and otherwise it does it at run time.  All that is needed to implement this is some way to say "If this object is constructed as a constexpr, the compiler need not destruct this object".  Constexpr is great, but it seems that D still has the edge in terms of non-template metaprogramming.

Comment: @RobertMason: Oh, compile time string transformation?  Now the question makes sense.  Yeah, C++ is lacking in that department.  It can be done with C++11, but it'd be hard.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, to a certain extent, see [the code example in this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType). You can create constexpr `conststr` objects and call some operations on them, but you cannot use them as non type template parameters.